# uniqe and repeated values in HTML table using Python/Django

Tags: python, django, random, unique

I need to build two 3x3 tables with numbers from 1 to 9. One table should have unique values.
I'm only able to get first table workin with `{{ random_number }}`  and can't figure out what's wrong with the other one `{{unique_random_number}}`. I'm getting [THIS](http://i60.tinypic.com/2h6rk8k.png).

Here's my code:

**urls.py**

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'devtask1.views.index'),
    url(r'^$', 'devtask1.views.index2'),


)
```

**views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from random import randint

def n():
    return randint(1,9)

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'random_number': n})

def un():
    for i in range(1,10):
        return i

def index2(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'unique_random_number': un})
```

**index.html**

```
            <table>
                 <tr>
                    <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ random_number }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table> 

            <table>
                 <tr>
                    <td>{{ unique_random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ unique_random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ unique_random_number }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ unique_random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ unique_random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ unique_random_number }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ unique_random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ unique_random_number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ unique_random_number }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass unique random number by building an array shuffling it and passing it through the context.

```
import random

def un():
    unums = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        unums.append(i)
    random.shuffle(unums)
    return unums
```

then in your html call the index, `unique_random_number[0]` through `unique_random_number[9]` they'll always be different because of the shuffle but you'll avoid the repeats.

Also, using django that table can be accomplished with a for loop much cleaner.

Comment: on python2, range(1,10) returns the list [1..9]. on python 3 it's an iterator. you could also `return random.shuffle(list(range(1, 10)))` for one-liners fans (it's even just a bit faster)

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error when I try {{unique_random_number[1]}} : Could not parse the remainder: '[1]' from 'u_random_number[1]'

Comment: My bad, I think proper syntax is `u_random_number.1`

Comment: Awesome, working nice :) Just one small thing. I think I have sth wrong in my urls.py. I've two lines there: ...index and ...index2, but only the first one works. If I turn off (#) ...index then I can view index2. Meaninig I can only view one table, either random_numbers or unique_random_numbers

Comment: These are two separate HTML files? what do you want it to be? just separate links, one to index and one to index2?  If so make sure that none of the `path/to/index` urls have a $ truncating it. `^path/to$` will not permit `path/to/index`. You might want to ask a separate question and give more details for this one though.

Comment: Nope, there is only one index.html file where I'd like to dispay 2 tables: one with random_numbers and another one with unique_random_numbers. I might have confused the urls.py idea thoroughly :/

Comment: Start a new question with some information. Comments is probably not the place to do this hah